# minimum number of vectors required to make a linear combination of a third vector in same space

Tags: vector-spaces

Was doing a question from Strang tonight.  In a 3d chart, there were three vectors U, V, and W.  It asked which vectors are combinations of U and V and *also* combinations of V and W.

I was thinking that cU+dV could only describe a plane  and that dV + eW could only describe a plane.  Where that plane intersects is V, which is the answer.

Of course, that is wrong.  The answer is All vectors are definable by linear combinations of U+V and V+W.

My defect is that I keep thinking you need one vector for each dimension in order to define all vectors in that R-n space.  I think this is wrong.

Want to doublecheck with you guys:  it seems true that for any n-Dimensional space you only need two non-colinear vectors to form a linear combination of all vectors in that R-n space?

Comment: Nope. For an $n$-dimensional vector space any basis consists of _exactly $n$ vectors_. Actually your first answer (wich you claim is wrong) is fine if the question was what is
$$\langle U, V \rangle \cap \langle W, V \rangle = \langle V \rangle$$
if $\{U, V, W\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: The text answer says the answer is All vectors are definable by linear combinations of U+V, and also combinations of V+W.  But your statement "for an *n*-dimensional vector space, any basis consists of exactly n vectors" means this shouldn't be correct?  IE: you'd need all three vectors to define any vector in the R3 space.

Comment: I love Strang's "Linear Algebra" and have enjoyed it a lot using it together with a text proving all the basic theorems of linear algebra, since it states more things than it proves. As to the vectors needed to generate an $n$-dimensional space, they cannot be less than $n$ and are exactly $n$ if they are linearly independent.

Comment: If that's what it says, it must be wrong. Chose $U,V,W = e_1, e_2, e_3$ the canonic basis vectors. $\langle U, V\rangle$ is the $\{z=0\}$ plane while $\langle V, W\rangle$ is the $\{x=0\}$ plane. Their intersection is the line $\{(0,y,0) | y\in \mathbb R\}$. Maybe the statement is
$$\langle U, V\rangle \cap \langle W, V \rangle \subset \langle U+V, V+W\rangle$$ wich is true?

Comment: I'll quote the question text exactly and the answer text exactly: "which vectors are combinations of U and V, and *also* combinations of V and W?"  and the answer text: "*All* vectors are combinations of U, V, and W"